# How to deactivate DragControls in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, drag-and-drop, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I would like to stop `DragControls` functionality after checkbox deselection. I try to use `removeEventListener`, but it seems not to be working. Do you have any idea how to deactivate `DragControls`?

```js
let dragControls;

function dragControlsStart() {
    dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
        controls.enabled = false;
    });
    dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
        controls.enabled = true;
    });
}

function dragControlsStop() {
    dragControls.removeEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
        controls.enabled = false;
    });
    dragControls.removeEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
        controls.enabled = true;
    });
}

function dragAndDropActivate() {
    let checkBox = document.getElementById("dragAndDropCheckbox");
    dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(meshes, camera, renderer.domElement);

    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        dragControlsStart();
    } 
    else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
        dragControlsStop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the controls have an [`activate`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/controls/DragControls.js#L35) and [`deactivate`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/controls/DragControls.js#L44) function on them that add and remove all the events, which sounds like what you're looking for:

```js
// create drag controls once and activate or deactivate 
const dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(meshes, camera, renderer.domElement);

function dragAndDropActivate() {
    let checkBox = document.getElementById("dragAndDropCheckbox");

    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        dragControls.activate();
    } 
    else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
        dragControls.deactivate();
    }
}
```

Another thing to note in your code is that the way you are adding and removing events will not work in `Javascript` because you are creating new function handles every time you call those functions. Instead you want to create a function once and use the same reference when adding or removing listeners.

```js
function dragEndCallback(event) {
    // ...
}

dragControls.addEventListener('dragEnd', dragEndCallback);
dragControls.removeEventListener('dragEnd', dragEndCallback);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```js
let dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(ArrayOfMesh, camera, renderer.domElement);

dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
    controls.enabled = false;
});

dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
    controls.enabled = true;
});

dragControls.deactivate();


function dragAndDropActivate() {

    let checkBox = document.getElementById("dragAndDropCheckbox");

    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        dragControls.activate();
    } 
    else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
        dragControls.deactivate();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `controls` refers to in your case?

Comment: @Bilal I guess it refers to new OrbitControls()